# Android Studio Button Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I believe I have correctly instantiated my button, but when I try to set the onClickListener, I get an error.

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.plant_based_diets)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        setCurrentFragment(thirdFragment)
    }
```

The error is on line 2, it reads: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dietcentral/com.example.dietcentral.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference.

Also here is the xml for the button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/plant_based_diets"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/plant_based_diets"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="114dp" />
```

How do I properly use the onclicklistener, I cannot find the solution elsewhere.

Comment: The code you provided looks correct, so the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: It looks like the button is not in the same xml file of your MainActivity

Comment: can you please update a code for setCurrentFragment(thirdFragment)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has something to do with the way you instantiate your button, but I'm not sure. This code should work;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button val = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plant_based_diets);
    val.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

}
```